# How do I install Lame in the Asunder program?

Tags: lame

I was trying to use Asunder but I get an error message saying that I need to have Lame installed in the path. I am just plain confused. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7):

There is a small issue with the installation of Asunder in that lame (which permits mp3 encoding under Asunder) is a '*suggested package*' rather than a mandatory part of the installation. Observe on my own system (arrows added by myself):

```
andrew@corinth:~$ sudo apt-get install asunder
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cdparanoia flac vorbis-tools wavpack
Suggested packages:              <---------------------------
  lame                           <---------------------------
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  asunder cdparanoia flac vorbis-tools wavpack
0 to upgrade, 5 to newly install, 0 to remove and 290 not to upgrade.
Need to get 465 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,971 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

This will lead to the error message that you have described:

[image]

The easy fix is to install the lame package *along with Asunder*:

```
sudo apt-get install asunder lame
```

and then Asunder will automagically pick up the lame package and all will be well :) See the relevant section of the preferences in Asunder below after a successful installation of lame *as well as* Asunder:

[image]

**Note:** Asunder will encode to several other formats so consider installing the required encoders for AAC, Opus, Musepack and Monkey's Audio as well...